# Language schools that teach Mayan languages around Lake Atlitlan, Guatemala?

Tags: study, languages, guatemala

I've been to Guatemala several times and always spend some time around Lake Atitlan. This is maybe the third most popular place to study Spanish in the country and has many language schools for foreigners, but most of the local people speak one of three Mayan languages and Spanish is their second language.

But I would be very much more interested to find out if there is a language school (or known private teacher) in San Pedro or one of the other villages than also teaches Tzotzil or one of the other local languages.

Comment: I studied K'iche' a couple of hours away in Santa Cruz. I'll contact my friends at the school there and see if they can put me in touch with someone teaching Tzotzil by the lake...

Comment: My friend in Santa Cruz informs me he is tapping his network down there. Also, he reminds me that the Mayan dialect spoken near Lake Atitlán is actually Tz'utujil (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz%27utujil_language)

Comment: Actually there are three Mayan languages spoken around the lake (Cakchiquel, Tzutuil and Quiché) but I prefer Tzutuhil since it's the one they speak in San Pedro where I've spent the most time and learned some words from a lady selling orange juice so I bought a book on it in Guatemala City.

Comment: Okay, I have a response listing an email address and phone number of someone who has a masters from Chi Pixab Institute and who sounds interested in teaching Tz'utujil. Email me at charliet@gmail.com and pass it along.

Comment: @Keyslinger: That's awesome. Only problem is this is really a model question from my past. The airline I used to fly to Mexico seems to have withdrawn the route so I don't know if I'll be travelling to this part of the world soon though it is maybe my favourite part )-:

Comment: Well, how about giving me the the check mark for my efforts :-)

Comment: Oh I thought you answered in a comment and that was somebody eles's answer... you got it!

Comment: Oops, should have put the comments in my answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cross-posted your question [here](http://www.xelapages.net/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=2589&p=10175#p10175). According to the forum's moderator, there is a well-connected Spanish teacher named Ramon who can probably help you. Looks like you can find his contact info here: http://www.sanpedrospanishschool.org/pages/contacts.html